D3 Multi-line chart shows 1 line instead of 3
I'm creating a 3-line chart using D3v7 but only 1 is showed. I'm unable to figure out why.
This is my dataset:

Current output:

Check out my code below:
// Setup SVG
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + paddingLeft + paddingRight)
    .attr("height", height + paddingTop + paddingBottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + paddingLeft + "," + paddingTop + ")");

// Setup scales
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

//Line generator
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {return x(d.monthyear); 
    })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.total); });

// Load data
d3.csv('adidas_west_sales.csv').then(buildLineChart);

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");

function buildLineChart(data)
{
    data.forEach(function(d)
    {
        d.MonthYear = parseTime(d.MonthYear);
    })

    var salesMethods = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(method)
    {   
        return {    method: method,
                    values: data.map(function(d) {
                        return {    monthyear: d.MonthYear,
                                    total: parseFloat(d[method])
                                }
                            }
                )}       
    });
    console.log(salesMethods);

    // Setup scales with data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.MonthYear;}));

    y.domain([
        d3.min(salesMethods, function(b) {
            return d3.min(b.values, function(d) {
                return d.total;
            });
        }),
        d3.max(salesMethods, function(b) {
            return d3.max(b.values, function(d) {
                return d.total;
            });
        })
    ]);
    
    colourScale.domain(salesMethods.map(function(c) { return c.method}))
// Add Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(24)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b-%Y")))
    .selectAll("text")  
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");;

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .text("Total Sale, $");

// Add lines


 const lineGraph =
    svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(salesMethods)
          .enter()
              .append("path")
              .attr('stroke', function(d, i) { return colourScale(i)})
              .attr('stroke-width', 1.25)
              .style("fill", "none")
              .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
       

}
salesMethods returns 3 values: "Online", "Instore", "Outlet" but there is only 1 line showed.
Is there something missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Your data is essentially an array of arrays.  When you get to adding your lines you need to have an outer data-bind so that d3 iterates over the outer array:
const lineGraph = svg
  .selectAll('.line')
  .data(salesMethods)
  .enter()
  .append('g') //<-- create a `g` for each outer-array
  .attr('class', 'line') 
  .append('path') //<-- then add the path
  .attr('stroke', function (d, i) {
    return colourScale(i);
  })
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.25)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .attr('d', function (d, i) {
    return line(d.values);
  });

Running code here.

This code snippet may resolve your problem.


// Sample data
    const data = [
        { monthYear: "2020-01", Instore: 5280000, Online: 143033, Outlet: 5525602 },
        { monthYear: "2020-02", Instore: 6588750, Online: 250233, Outlet: 3131293 },
        { monthYear: "2020-03", Instore: 7013750, Online: 181349, Outlet: 121259 },
        { monthYear: "2020-04", Instore: 9786250, Online: 251204, Outlet: 4461817 },
        { monthYear: "2020-05", Instore: 9032500, Online: 226795, Outlet: 4461817 },
        { monthYear: "2020-06", Instore: 8606250, Online: 223569, Outlet: 4461817 },
        { monthYear: "2020-07", Instore: 12758750, Online: 326500, Outlet: 4461817 },
        { monthYear: "2020-08", Instore: 3923750, Online: 94926, Outlet: 4461817 },
        { monthYear: "2020-11", Instore: 5280000, Online: 102780, Outlet: 4027729 },
        { monthYear: "2020-12", Instore: 5280000, Online: 117064, Outlet: 4461817 },
        { monthYear: "2021-01", Instore: 2300000, Online: 3454747, Outlet: 18660281 },
        { monthYear: "2021-02", Instore: 2573750, Online: 2974546, Outlet: 10743427 },
        { monthYear: "2021-03", Instore: 2851500, Online: 3283899, Outlet: 6204093 },
        { monthYear: "2021-04", Instore: 2795000, Online: 3608105, Outlet: 10785614 },
        { monthYear: "2021-05", Instore: 3563250, Online: 4503178, Outlet: 15244834 },
        { monthYear: "2021-06", Instore: 5426250, Online: 5837664, Outlet: 4712980 },
        { monthYear: "2021-07", Instore: 6420000, Online: 6422120, Outlet: 4985756 },
        { monthYear: "2021-08", Instore: 5280000, Online: 6369496, Outlet: 4260082 },
        { monthYear: "2021-09", Instore: 3145000, Online: 5210276, Outlet: 2950776 },
        { monthYear: "2021-10", Instore: 3471250, Online: 3986226, Outlet: 2442733 },
        { monthYear: "2021-11", Instore: 4271750, Online: 5183515, Outlet: 3509722 },
        { monthYear: "2021-12", Instore: 5576250, Online: 6302376, Outlet: 3737583 }
    ];

    // Chart dimensions
    const width = 800;
    const height = 500;
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 100 };

    // Create SVG
    const svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    // Scales
    const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");
    const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => parseTime(d.monthYear)))
        .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d3.max([d.Instore, d.Online, d.Outlet]))])
        .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

    // Line generator
    const line = d3.line()
        .x(d => xScale(parseTime(d.monthYear)))
        .y(d => yScale(d.value));

    // Colors
    const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["Instore", "Online", "Outlet"])
        .range(["blue", "green", "red"]);

    // Draw lines
    ["Instore", "Online", "Outlet"].forEach(type => {
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", colors(type))
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("d", d3.line()
                .x(d => xScale(parseTime(d.monthYear)))
                .y(d => yScale(d[type]))
            );
    });

    // Axes
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m")));
 #chart {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>




I'm using D3 v7, this code doesnt work for me

I am here using d3.v7 (7.8.5), kindly mention your d3 exact version @vyclarks

this is my version: 

I followed your code but it doesn't work, no lines were showed. How about my code? I don't know what is the issue

The accepted answer is simply wrong, your code is working as it is.
The problem is that you are selecting two paths that already exist -- the x and y axis -- and binding data to them.
Do you want to be sure that this is the case? Just select something else and you'll see your code works:
 const lineGraph =
     svg.selectAll(".myPath")
         .data(salesMethods)
         .enter()
         .append("path") etc...

